# I'm trying to extract emails, and I'm getting a TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, docx, python-re

I'm attempting to take emails from 500 word documents, and use findall to extract them into excel. This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx.api import Document
import os
import re

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user1\\test')
path = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\test'
output_path = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\test2'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('{}/docx_emails.xlsx'.format(output_path),engine='xlsxwriter')


worddocs_list = []
for filename in list(os.listdir(path)):
    wordDoc = Document(os.path.join(path, filename))
    worddocs_list.append(wordDoc)

data = []    
    
for wordDoc in worddocs_list:
    match = re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+',wordDoc)
    data.append(match)
   

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

print(df)
```

and I'm getting an error showing:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 19>()
     17 data = []    
     19 for wordDoc in worddocs_list:
---> 20     match = re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+',wordDoc)
     21     data.append(match)
     24 df = pd.DataFrame(data)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\re.py:241, in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    233 def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):
    234     """Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.
    235 
    236     If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return
   (...)
    239 
    240     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 241     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks.

Comment: Look at `wordDoc`. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `wordDoc` variable doesn't contain a string, it contains a Document object. You need to look at the `docx.api` documention to see how to get the body of the Word document as a string out of the object.

It [looks like](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#id1) you first have to get the Paragraphs with `wordDoc.paragraphs` and then ask each one for its `text`, so maybe something like this?

```
documentText = '\n'.join([p.text for p in wordDoc.paragraphs])
```

And then use that as the string to match against:

```
match = re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', documentText)
```

If you're going to be using the same regular expression over and over, though, you should probably compile it into a Pattern object first instead of passing it as a string to `findall` every time:

```
regex = re.compile(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+')
for filename in list(os.listdir(path)):
    wordDoc = Document(os.path.join(path, filename))
    documentText = '\n'.join([p.text for p in wordDoc.paragraphs])
    match = regex.findall(documentText)
```